# find the general element of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $5,4,\frac{11}{3},\frac{7}{2},\frac{17}{5}$

I have translated it to $5,4,3+\frac{2}{3},3+\frac{1}{2},3+\frac{2}{5}$ and that the elements in the  even palces are smaller than the odd but can not see a pattern

Comment: sometimes it is useful to write $2/4$ instead of $1/2$  ... If the sequence of denominators can be made "smoother" by some simple expansion I'd do that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And now ?
$$\frac 51,\frac 82,\frac{11}{3},\frac{14}{4},\frac{17}{5}$$